# Asus Vivotab K0Y refuses to detect a bootable media

Tags: boot, system-installation, uefi, asus

I have a K0Y with a 2-core z2760 („Altough the Atom cores theoretically support 64 Bit, the Z2760 is only specified for 32 Bit operating systems“) and a broken TS.
I've tried to plug an USB hub in and to connect both keyboard and flash stick, and to connect a keyboard directly, having a bootable MicroSD in it's slot.
None worked, it just ignores any external bootable media.
I've also tried to enter an Administrator password and to disable the Secure Boot, it worked, but there are still no Ubuntu option in the Boot Priority list. Also, Fast Boot and Quiet Boot are still active and I can't disable them (they return to Enabled state after restart).
I've tried many .iso files, both 64-bit (which should attempt to boot and return the error message, but they don't) and 32-bit (which should work). Right now, I have a 128 Mb MicroSD with Bionic Beaver 32-bit Mini-ISO, created with Startup Disk Creator (from the default Lubuntu-64 20.04 application set).
I have however only two boot options: „Windows Boot Manager“ and „Disabled“. Setting to „Disabled“ changes nothing: Win8 still starts, instead of having some boot error.
Is it some lack of EFI partition on a bootable MicroSD or some sort of a Suspend feature, integrated into UEFI and preventing from booting another OS? Or something else?

Comment: Hello. In the boot list there wont be Ubuntu listed unless it is installed. Your question reads like you have not been able to install it. What version of Ubuntu are you trying to install to this very low powered machine? What is this? broken TS.

Comment: TS=Touch Screen.  What version of Ubuntu are you trying to boot from?  How did you create your bootable SDCard / USB?  Are you using a 32-bit or 64-bit version of Ubuntu?  Your processor in that tablet only supports 32-bit OSes.  So, if you're trying Ubuntu 20.04 it will not boot since there is no 32-bit version of it.  Please edit your question and give us some more details about how you have tried to setup Ubuntu.  Thank you!